# Trace writes in event log though "TextWriter" trace listener used

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I am using trace writer and have register only TextWriterTraceListener.

```
objStream = new FileStream(logFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Append);
TextWriterTraceListener objTraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(objStream);
Trace.Listeners.Add(objTraceListener);
```

If this dll used with any other .net applications it will write trace in a text file properly, but along with some Applications like Dynamics AX, I found along with Textfile it writes trace logs into Event viewer as well.

Why does the trace write to event log?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're just adding another listener to the `Listener` collection, you're not replacing the one already there. Try doing this:

```
Trace.Listeners.Clear();
Trace.Listeners.Add(objTraceListener);
```

Comment: Thanks Alex. Let me try this.